# App rejected because of age consent with UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, appstore-approval

My app has just been just been rejected from the appStore because it has UIWebView without the  17+ age consent. The app is very much designed for children and families and I really don't want to put an age restriction in the appStore details. The UIWebview loads with bing for the the user to download whatever images. My questions is .... is there code to turn on safe search filters in Bing and Google that I can load into my webView ???

Comment: Um, use of a `UIWebView` alone does not get you rejected for this. I have put several apps into the app store that have `UIWebView`s and are not rated 17+. It is because of the *content* that they reject. What do you use the `UIWebView` for? What content were the reviewers able to load into your app that you did not intended for them to load? You are able to ask them questions about their rejections.

Comment: Basically, my app is to help with homeWork. The UIWebView is for the user to download images on any subject. The user can than take a screen shot of what is displayed in the webView. When Apple reviewed my app I was bit shocked because the review included screen shots of my app with the UIWebView displaying porn (blurred out).I was shocked, because the intention of the app was not to search porn, But the reviewer obviously made the point that this was possible with my app. Is MacOSX for 17+ ???

Comment: Thanks @BergQuester for your comment. Helps to have actual, real-world evidence.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about apple app review policies

Comment: Have you tried using any URL parameters or cookies?

Comment: Have you resolved the age consent issue?

Comment: @Wain... Can you suggest how it could be done because I too want my app in 4+ category but apple is insisting for 17+ because of the content.I am unable to block the adult content completely.I have asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388897/how-to-restrict-adult-content-on-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have essentially implemented a web browser as part of your app. Like it or not, Apple rates web browsers as NC-17. Both the [Chrome](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chrome/id535886823?mt=8) and [Opera](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opera-mini-web-browser/id363729560?mt=8) have this rating.

I am not finding any frameworks to do filtering for you, however there does seem to be a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604440/url-filtering-for-uiwebview-on-the-iphone).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `&adlt=strict` to the URL will enforce strict Safe Search on Bing.

Answer (score 0):

Even adding a strict safe search isn't going to help you here. Unfortunately, if you build a web image browser that you could even theoretically use to access content that is rated 17+, you're going to get a 17+ tag here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a browser on the App Store. Apple will rarely accept anything with a web view to not be 17+. If you can search anything, it  has to be 17+.

I have apps that load a page that show grades for school. These are accepted because users cannot go to Google or Bing or Yahoo! and search. So If you want to not be 17+ rating on the app, you have to have a site that people can't get to a search engine and search around.

Comment: to all answers - Thank you all for your comments. Yea I realise now the problem isn't the UIwebView its the fact you can search. I'll have to go with 17+ tag but I'll put an explanation in the AppStore description. Seems a shame to put a 17+ restriction on a app designed for families !!!