# How to restrict adult content on UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, browser, uiwebview, search-engine

I am working on an app which is specifically designed for **kids**.So we are giving some search option for the kids through `google search engine` and making it sure that search should be safe which we are doing by adding **&safe=activate** in the url.

This is working fine and the search content is restricted.Now user enters another search engine in google say **bing** and open it on `UIWebview`. So like google it is also restricting the adult content but asking permission of age limit.If kid agrees that he is **18+ age** then he can browse adult content using bing.

I want to make app in such a way that it should never show adult content on google search on `UIWebview`.

I have the following doubts.

1. How would we verify the url loading on `UIWebview` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is an adult website.I tried to change the url `(by adding &safe=activate every time when user loads subsequent UIWebview pages)` but it is assigned **readonly**  property and we can't change it.So is there anyway to control there?
2. Should I make a list of adult websites in my app and check every time when url is loaded in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.
3. Is there any possible way to restrict search engines like bing not to ask kid about age permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can use microsofts project oxford to identify adult images. Maybe that could help...

https://www.projectoxford.ai/demo/visions#Analysis